# Android Studio 3 - EOCD Signature not found

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am facing this problem after upgrading my Android Studio from 2.3 to 3.1.2. I've already searched for the solutions and the issue seems to be connected to the multidexing. However, I've added multidex support as per android guidelines and I still get this problem. Any help is appreciated!

```
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task

':app:transformNativeLibsWithMergeJniLibsForArmAmazonfiretvfreeDebug'.  
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:100)   
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)   
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)     
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:62)   
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)     
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:60)   
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:97)   
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:87)     
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)   
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)     
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)   
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)     
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)   
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)   
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)  
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)  
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)   
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)   
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)     
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)     
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:123)  
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)    
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:104)    
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)     
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:626)   
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:581)   
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)   
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)   
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)    
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)  
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)  
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by: java.io.UncheckedIOException: java.io.IOException: Failed to read zip file 'C:\Users\Дима\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\adal-1.13.2.aar\0609b8bbdaebc86f749d40642893ae87\jni'.  
at com.android.builder.merge.LazyIncrementalFileMergerInputs.load(LazyIncrementalFileMergerInputs.java:88) 
at com.android.builder.merge.LazyIncrementalFileMergerInputs.lambda$fromNew$0(LazyIncrementalFileMergerInputs.java:59)
at com.android.apkzlib.utils.CachedSupplier.get(CachedSupplier.java:81)     
at com.android.builder.merge.LazyIncrementalFileMergerInput.lambda$new$2(LazyIncrementalFileMergerInput.java:138)   
at com.android.apkzlib.utils.CachedSupplier.get(CachedSupplier.java:81)     
at com.android.builder.merge.LazyIncrementalFileMergerInput.open(LazyIncrementalFileMergerInput.java:225)   
at com.android.builder.merge.DelegateIncrementalFileMergerInput.open(DelegateIncrementalFileMergerInput.java:49)    at com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList.forEach(ImmutableList.java:397)  
at com.android.builder.merge.IncrementalFileMerger.merge(IncrementalFileMerger.java:73)     
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.MergeJavaResourcesTransform.transform(MergeJavaResourcesTransform.java:411)     
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:221)  
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:217)  
at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:102) 
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask.transform(TransformTask.java:212)   at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor603.invoke(Unknown Source)    
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)    
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     
at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)    
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:46)   
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)   
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)   
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:121)    
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)  
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)  
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)   
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)   
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:110)    
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:92)    ... 32 more Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to read zip file 'C:\Users\Дима\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\adal-1.13.2.aar\0609b8bbdaebc86f749d40642893ae87\jni'.     at com.android.apkzlib.zip.ZFile.<init>(ZFile.java:525)     
at com.android.apkzlib.zip.ZFile.<init>(ZFile.java:447)     
at com.android.apkzlib.zip.ZFile.<init>(ZFile.java:433)     
at com.android.builder.files.RelativeFiles.fromZip(RelativeFiles.java:119)  
at com.android.builder.merge.LazyIncrementalFileMergerInputs.load(LazyIncrementalFileMergerInputs.java:86)  ... 59 more Caused by: java.io.IOException: EOCD signature not found in the last 0 bytes of the file.   
at com.android.apkzlib.zip.ZFile.readEocd(ZFile.java:786) 
at com.android.apkzlib.zip.ZFile.readData(ZFile.java:596)   
at com.android.apkzlib.zip.ZFile.<init>(ZFile.java:510)     
... 63 
more
```

Comment: Did you try to remove this file from cache `Failed to read zip file 'C:\Users\Дима\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\adal-1.13.2.aar\0609b8bbdaebc86f749d40642893ae87\jni'.` and resync your project? Or even clear whole Gradle cache.

Comment: I've found a solution. I updated com.microsoft.aad to 1.14.0 and the problem is gone now.

Answer (score 0):

Just Delete **debug apk** and **release apk** from project folder and rebuild your project. it will work.